# pyftdi: SPI - CLK idle state inverted (mode3)

Tags: python, spi

I'm working with the following setup:

FT4232H -- SPI-sensor (mode 3)

Code below should work with Copy&paste and python 3.7.
After a powercycle the CLK-Pin of FTDI is high. Once the "`spi.get()`-line" is passed, it's idle low. It operates normaly during a transaction, but my sensor returns junk, because it assumes the CLK idle high.

Is this an issue with my FT4232H or a bug in the library (30.3 - pyftdi)? Does someone know wht I've done wrong?

```
from pyftdi.spi import SpiController

spi = SpiController()
spi.configure('ftdi://ftdi:4232h/1')
# assumption: after the line CLK should be idle high (which is not)
slave = spi.get_port(cs=0, freq=1E5, mode=3) 
read_byte=slave.exchange([0x00], 1).tobytes()
print(read_byte)
```